ошибка при вводе sudo apt update
пытался установить майн по видосу школьника но на моменте ввода sudo apt update выдаёт ошибки:
E: Репозиторий «cdrom://Kubuntu 22.04.3 LTS _Jammy Jellyfish_ - Release amd64 (20230807.1) jammy Release» не содержит файла Release.
N: Обновление из этого репозитория нельзя выполнить безопасным способом, поэтому по умолчанию он отключён.
N: Информацию о создании репозитория и настройках пользователя смотрите в справочной странице apt-secure(8).
W: Ошибка GPG: https://repo.yandex.ru/yandex-browser/deb stable InRelease: Следующие подписи не могут быть проверены, так как недоступен открытый ключ: NO_PUBKEY 60B9CD3A083A7A9A
E: Репозиторий «https://repo.yandex.ru/yandex-browser/deb stable InRelease» не подписан.
N: Обновление из этого репозитория нельзя выполнить безопасным способом, поэтому по умолчанию он отключён.
N: Информацию о создании репозитория и настройках пользователя смотрите в справочной странице apt-secure(8).
W: Ошибка GPG: https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease: Следующие подписи не могут быть проверены, так как недоступен открытый ключ: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F
E: Репозиторий «https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease» не подписан.
N: Обновление из этого репозитория нельзя выполнить безопасным способом, поэтому по умолчанию он отключён.
N: Информацию о создании репозитория и настройках пользователя смотрите в справочной странице apt-secure(8).
E: Репозиторий «https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu jammy Release» не содержит файла Release.
N: Обновление из этого репозитория нельзя выполнить безопасным способом, поэтому по умолчанию он отключён.
N: Информацию о создании репозитория и настройках пользователя смотрите в справочной странице apt-secure(8).


Ну, добавь ключи gpg тех проектов, на которые ругается. Маны есть на самих сайтах.
